# Reading file made by cmd, results in 3 weird symbols

Tags: c++, file, c++11, visual-c++, cmd

Im using this piece of code to read a file to a string, and its working perfectly with files manually made in notepad, notepad++ or other text editors:

```
std::string utils::readFile(std::string file)
{
    std::ifstream t(file);
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return str;
}
```

When I create a file via notepad (or any other editor) and save it to something, I get this result in my program:
[image: ImageShouldBeValid]

But when I create a file via CMD (example command below), and run my program, I receive an unexpected result:
[image: ImageShouldBeValid]  
    `cmd /C "hostname">"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\lel.txt" & exit`

Result:
[image: ImageShouldBeValid]

When I open this file generated by CMD (lel.txt), this is the file contents:
[image: ImageShouldBeValid]

If I edit the generated file (lel.txt) with notepad (adding a space to the end of the file), and try running my program again, I get the same weird 3char result.

What might cause this? How can I read a file made via cmd, correctly?

**EDIT**
I changed my command (now using powershell), and added a function I found, named SkipBOM, and now it works:

```
powershell -command "hostname | Out-File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\lel.txt" -encoding "UTF8""
```

SkipBOM:

```
void SkipBOM(std::ifstream &in)
{
    char test[3] = { 0 };
    in.read(test, 3);
    if ((unsigned char)test[0] == 0xEF &&
        (unsigned char)test[1] == 0xBB &&
        (unsigned char)test[2] == 0xBF)
    {
        return;
    }
    in.seekg(0);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't surprise me if it's something related to a rather infamous notepad "[bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)"

Comment: it could be encoding issue, the file's encoding may be  UNICODE (UTF-16) on windows , while your program deals with ASCII

Comment: Please do not use images to post your code. It makes it impossible to copy/paste into a code editor for testing, and you have the code as text right in front of your face. It's much easier to simply copy/paste code than it is to create an image and upload it. Images should be used **only when necessary** to demonstrate a problem that can't be shown otherwise.

Comment: I will add the code provided in the image. [Edit] Added!

Comment: @DavidHaim Indeed, when I click "Save-as" with notepad, it says UNICODE. Is there any way of saving it as "ANSI" via cmd?

Comment: so here is your problem.. I don't know how to so it.

Comment: Whatever is creating your output is writing a BOM to the file, but the messagebox interprets the bytes separately as 0xff 0xfe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly **BOM** (Byte Order Mark) : see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which means that your file is saved in UNICODE with BOM.
There is a way to use C++ streams to read files with BOM (you have to use converters) - let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Actually, I re-did my code, and added the BOM function I have. Editing my question right now!

Comment: Do you want to just fix the file (to make it ASCII) or read the UNICODE file in C++ properly ?

Comment: Used powershell to save the output as UTF8, and skipping BOM. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is how unicode looks when treated as an ANSI string. In notepad use File - Save As to see what the current format of a file is.

Now CMD uses OEM font, which is the same as ANSI for English characters. So **any unicode will be converted to OEM by CMD**.  Perhaps you are grabbing the data yourself.

In VB you would use StrConv to convert it.